# Is it possible to download using the Windows command line?

Tags: command-line, web

Without using any non-standard (Windows included) utilities, is it possible to download using the Windows command line?

The preferred version is Windows XP, but it's also interesting to know for newer versions.

To further clarify my question:

- It has to be using HTTP
- The file needs to be saved
- Standard clean Windows install, no extra tools

So basically, since everybody is screaming *[Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)*, I want simple Wget functionality, without using Wget.

Comment: More ideas in "If the only browser in Windows is dead, how to connect to the Internet?" at http://superuser.com/questions/50427/if-the-only-browser-in-windows-is-dead-how-to-connect-to-the-internet/

Comment: And which out of the dozen Windows XP versions would that be?

Comment: Let's say it can be any windows XP SP2 version and everything released later.

Comment: @arjan Interesting question, but there's still no definitive answer.

Comment: I should have asked for "edition". Like Starter, Home, Professional, Media Center, Tablet, maybe even Embedded (good change for tools there I guess!)... Or the European versions without Windows Media Player. :-)

Comment: More answers to this question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619088/windows-batch-file-file-download-from-a-url

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can write a VBScript and run it from the command line

Create a file `downloadfile.vbs` and insert the following lines of code:

```vbs
' Set your settings
    strFileURL = "http://www.it1.net/images/it1_logo2.jpg"
    strHDLocation = "c:\logo.jpg"

' Fetch the file
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
Set objFSO = Nothing

objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Run it from the command line as follows:

```
cscript.exe downloadfile.vbs
```

Comment: I wonder if this relies on Internet Explorer, but I guess this would be a fine answer for "If the only browser in Windows is dead, how to connect to the Internet?" at http://superuser.com/questions/50427/if-the-only-browser-in-windows-is-dead-how-to-connect-to-the-internet/ :-)

Comment: that's if permission to cscript.exe is permitted

Comment: I can confirm that I have tested this script in **Windows PE 5.1** and it has worked like a charm. I intend to use it for offline deployment, in order to check the version of the platform in the USB drive against a text file stored on the server.

Answer (score 76):

Starting with Windows 7, I believe there's one single method that hasn't been mentioned yet that's easy:

Syntax:

```
bitsadmin  /transfer job_name       /download  /priority priority   URL  local\path\file
```

Example:

```
bitsadmin  /transfer mydownloadjob  /download  /priority normal  ^
                  http://example.com/filename.zip  C:\Users\username\Downloads\filename.zip
```

<sup>(Broken into two separate lines with `^` for readability
(to avoid scrolling).)</sup>

**Warning:** As pointed out in the comments,
the `bitsadmin` help message starts by saying:

```
BITSAdmin is deprecated and is not guaranteed to be available in future versions of Windows.
Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets.
```

... but another comment reported that it works on Windows 8.

Comment: This looks like the kind of tool the OP was looking for, but it is not a standard part of a Windows install, you have to install it separately.  Useful tool though.

Comment: it is part of windows7.

Comment: didn't work on my windows 7...

Comment: This should have been the top-voted answer. bitsadmin is deprecated in favor of Windows powershell though.

Comment: It was part of my windows 7 install. Thanks!

Comment: Confirm working on Win7

Comment: Note: *BITSAdmin is deprecated and is not guaranteed to be available in future versions of Windows.
Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets.*

Comment: @jyzuz  It is part of Windows 7 Ultimate. I don't know what you have.

Comment: Doesn't run from a Batch file via task scheduler. I get this error: `Unable to add file - 0x800704dd
The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not logged on to the network. The specified service does not exist.`

Comment: Confirm working on this Win8

Comment: @VaibhavGarg you need to make sure the name of the downloaded file is exactly as appears on the last part of the download URL (after the final '/' and preceding, say, the '.exe')

Comment: It's present in Win10… though doesn't handle FTP protocol :(

Comment: It's not present on my Win10 - at least not in safe mode.

Comment: Must be the only answer in the whole internet about using cmd to download a file without powershell or the need to install tools like curl and wget.

Answer (score 39):

Windows 7 includes PowerShell and there's pretty much nothing you can't do with PowerShell.

[Native alternative to wget in Windows PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/questions/362152/native-alternative-to-wget-in-windows-powershell)

Comment: (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('someurl', 'somepath')

Comment: **Powershell** is for _Powerrangers_ ! How kool is that and why the heck didn't I know about this? Byebye `cmd`.

Comment: from cmd.exe: `powershell -command "& { iwr http://www.it1.net/it1_logo2.jpg -OutFile logo.jpg }"`. also works from the run prompt

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing you can't do without powershell.  It's a real turing tarpit :)

Comment: @JanusTroelsen my version of PowerShell responded "The term 'iwr' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,..." but after some investigation this similar worked: `powershell -command "$clnt = new-object System.Net.WebClient; $clnt.DownloadFile(\"https://host/name\", \"outpufilename\")"`

Answer (score 26):

PowerShell (included with Windows 8 and included with .NET for earlier releases) has this capability. The `powershell` command allows running arbitrary PowerShell commands from the command line or a `.bat` file. Thus, the following line is what's wanted:

```
powershell -command "& { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://example.com/', 'c:\somefile') }"
```

Comment: @harrymc sure it's an answer. it downloads a file. what more do you want?

Comment: (1) Some text to explain what does this one-liner, (2) Verify that your answer isn't an alternative formulation to a previous answer, since if it is, it should at most be expressed as a comment on that answer.

Comment: What version of Windows and PowerShell is required for this to work?

Comment: this doesn't work in Windows Server 2012 FYI, it throws a MethodInvocationException

Answer (score 19):

I found a way of doing it, but really, just install [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget).

You can use Internet Explorer from a command line (iexplore.exe) and then enter a URL as an argument. So, run:

```
iexplore.exe http://blah.com/filename.zip
```

Whatever the file is, you'll need to specify it doesn't need confirmation ahead of time. Lo and behold, it will automatically perform the download. So yes, it is technically possible, but good lord do it in a different way.

Comment: I know wget is a much better way, it's just a hypothetical question ;) Your answer comes pretty close, but still requires user intervention(clicking "Save", or configuring not to display this dialog)

Comment: Like I said, you have to deselect the option to prompt to save for that file type.  For example, download a zip file, disable that prompt, and then in the future any zip files accessed from the command line will automatically save.

Answer (score 14):

[Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) (not to be confused with Internet Explorer) can download files via HTTP. Just enter the URL into the Address bar. Or from the command line, for example, `C:\windows\explorer.exe http://somewhere.com/filename.ext`.

You get the classic *File Download* prompt. Unless the file is a type that Windows Explorer knows how to display inline, (.html, .jpg, .gif), in which case you would then need to right-click to save it.

I just tested this on my [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) image of a virgin install of Windows XP 2002 SP1, and it works fine.

Comment: this requires user interaction. probably not what most people who want to download a file from the command prompt want

Comment: Nowadays, it depends on your default-browser. Mine is chrome, and it auto-downloads to a known location, so I consider this solution to be sufficient for my needs. Thx!

Comment: This just calls up iexplorer.exe (by default) and additionally requires the site to be added to security exceptions on server installations.

Answer (score 7):

You can use (in a standard Windows bat):

```
powershell -command "& { iwr http://www.it1.net/it1_logo2.jpg -OutFile logo.jpg }"
```

It seems to require PowerShell v4...

(Thanks to [that comment](https://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line#comment988261_59486) and [this one](https://superuser.com/a/758510/136024))

Answer (score 6):

Use FTP.

From the command line:

```
ftp ftp.somesite.com
user
password
```

etc. FTP is included in every Windows version I can remember; probably not in 3.1, maybe not in [Windows 95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_95), but certainly everything after that.

@RM: It is going to be rough if you don't want to download any other tools. There exists a command line [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) is designed to do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: +1 good answer.  ftp is pretty universal, as long as the server you're trying to download from supports it.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I wasn't more specific, I meant using HTTP.

Comment: This will not work with most FTP servers as passive mode is not supported by this Windows ftp client (with NATs inbetween passive mode is required).

Comment: @PeterMortensen It also doesn't remotely answer the question since he edited it to specify he was looking for wget functionality. But don't let that stop you from resurrecting a 7 year old wrong answer just to add some pedantry.

Answer (score 5):

Use PowerShell like this:

1. Create a download.ps1 file:

   ```
   param($url, $filename)
   $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
   $client.DownloadFile( $url, $filename)
   ```
2. Now you can download a file like this:

   ```
   powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
   powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "download.ps1" "http://somewhere.com/filename.ext" "d:\filename.ext"
   ```

Comment: This works, even on Windows XP 64-bit, PowerShell 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

On Win CMD (if you have write access):

```
set url=https://www.nsa.org/content/hl-images/2017/02/09/NSA.jpg
set file=file.jpg
certutil -urlcache -split -f %url% %file%
echo Done.
```

Built in Windows app. No need for external downloads.

Tested on Win 10

Answer (score 2):

If you have python installed here's an example which fetches the get-pip.py from the web

```
python -c "import urllib; urllib.urlretrieve ('https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py', r'C:\python27\Tools\get-pip.py')"
```

Answer (score 2):

File can be download via below method

bitsadmin /transfer wcb /priority high https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/content/documents/Agenda21.pdf C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell Update\Agenda21.pdf

Answer (score 2):

From Windows 10 build 17063 and later, ‘Curl’ is now included, so that you can execute it directly from Cmd.exe or PowerShell.exe.

For example:

```
C:\>curl.exe -V
curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL
```

To download a file:

```
curl.exe -O https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/Img/logo.svg
```

Answer (score 1):

If you install Telnet, I imagine you could make a HTTP request to a server to download a file.

You can also install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), and use [wget](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2008-06/msg00005.html) to download a file as well. This is a very easy way to download files from the command line.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'cygwin' counts as a non-standard utility ;-)

Comment: Telnet is an interesting option, is there a way to pipe the output to a file without corrupting it? And can we pipe HTTP GET command into telnet to make the request?

Comment: Install telnet? Telnet is like ftp; it comes with windows. Don't know about redirecting the output though.

Comment: For XP (as in the question) telnet is installed by default, but I heard that on Vista that's no longer the case?  But no, it does not allow for file downloads, unless all is returned in a single HTTP response, *and* one can strip the headers and decode the stuff on the command line as well. Quite unlikely one can control that.

Comment: Why install cygwin just to use wget? There is a native win32 binary available.

Comment: @DaveParillo: My answer was posted before the requirements of clean install.
@Robert: I'm not sure. I've never used telnet in this fashion. I said 'I imagine you could'. 
@SatanicPuppy: As Arjan pointed out, it's not in Vista by default.
@Manni: I did not know there was a win32 binary available.

Comment: @EvilChookie Telnet comes with Windows Vista+, it simply isn't **enabled** by default in these versions of Windows.

Comment: @user2428118  the telnet service exists sure, but the telnet CLIENT does not exist in Win7, telnet.exe it can be copied from XP though.

Comment: I have a strange telnet.exe on win7 32bit ultimate here C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-telnet-client_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_b807e788865dfff7> and similar on a win7 64bit ultimate C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-telnet-client_31bf385
0.16385_none_1426830c3ebb712d>  but it/they don't  do anything. A working telnet.exe has to be copied from XP

Comment: @barlop The client does exist. You can just [go to here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-windows-features-on-off#1TC=windows-7) and enable the Telnet client.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Linux application Wget on Windows. It can be downloaded from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm. You can then issue the command 'wget (inserturlhere)' or any other [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in your command prompt, and it will allow you to download that URL/file/image.

Comment: Strangely this version is not always compatible. On my Windows 7 computer it wasn't because libraries were missing. You'd want to use wget without any extra libraries most of the time. http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you can download using the command line in Windows:

1. You can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

   Note: the included apps are not native Linux apps. You must rebuild your application from source if you want to run on Windows.
2. Using telnet it's possible to make a request but you won't see any processing.
3. You can write bat or VBS scripts.
4. Write your own program that you can run from cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

In default Windows, you can't download via HTTP.  Windows is a GUI-centric OS, so it lacks many of the commandline tools you'd find in other OS's, like `wget`, which would be the prime candidate.

`System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile()`, a function in the `WiniNet` API, can download files, but I'm not sure how far you're getting into actual development vs. a batch file.

Comment: I understand it's possible using wget, but my question states without the use non-standard windows utils.