# Installing Ruby on a windows box with only SSH access

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, ruby

I'm trying to run ruby on a fresh windows server.  Is there a way to do this with only SSH access?

Comment: Do you mean you have sshd running on a Windows server installation? Why no Remote Desktop access?

Answer (score 0):

Download [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/), run the installer with `/verysilent /norestart /dir=C:\Ruby`

---

- [InnoSetup command line](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/InnoSetup_Switches_ExitCodes.html)

Comment: How do I download ruby installer from the command line?

Comment: @Justin: If you have SSH, chances are you can upload it from your own PC with SFTP (using WinSCP). Otherwise, there's a command-line `ftp` client, and PowerShell (comes with Server 2008) has `System.Net.WebClient` and `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: you can use iexpore to download it via command line - iexplore.exe http://blah.com/filename.zip amongst other methods http://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line

Comment: @Journeyman: Internet Explorer requires a graphical session to work. SSH doesn't have that, at least not on Windows.