# Native alternative to wget in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I know I can download and install the aformentioned library (wget for Windows), but my question is this:

In Windows PowerShell, is there a native alternative to `wget`?

I need `wget` simply to retrieve a file from a given URL with HTTP GET. For instance:

```
wget http://www.google.com/
```

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Here's a simple PS 3.0 and later one-liner that works and doesn't involve much PS barf:

```
wget http://blog.stackexchange.com/ -OutFile out.html
```

Note that:

- `wget` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`
- Invoke-WebRequest returns a [HtmlWebResponseObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.htmlwebresponseobject_members%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which contains a lot of useful HTML parsing properties such as Links, Images, Forms, InputFields, etc., but in this case we're just using the raw Content
- The file contents are stored in memory before writing to disk, making this approach unsuitable for downloading large files
- On Windows Server Core installations, you'll need to write this as

  ```
  wget http://blog.stackexchange.com/ -UseBasicParsing -OutFile out.html
  ```
- Prior to Sep 20 2014, I suggested

  ```
  (wget http://blog.stackexchange.com/).Content >out.html
  ```

  as an answer.  However, this doesn't work in all cases, as the `>` operator (which is an alias for `Out-File`) converts the input to Unicode.

If you are using Windows 7, you will need to install version 4 or newer of the Windows Management Framework.

You may find that doing a `$ProgressPreference = "silentlyContinue"` before `Invoke-WebRequest` will significantly improve download speed with large files; this variable controls whether the progress UI is rendered.

Comment: This is now the correct answer, and I ran into wget accidentally testing if I had the actual wget installed. Annoying that it can't get the filename easily (you have to specify it in the output redirection), but this option has a better UI than the real wget (in my opinion) so there's that.

Comment: But [Windows 7 only comes with PowerShell 2.0](http://superuser.com/questions/650814), and the result will be "The term 'Invoke-WebRequest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, ...".

Comment: Powershell 4 is available for Windows 7 -- it's part of the Windows Management Framework.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

Comment: Fair warning: This method will put the entire content of the file into memory before writing it out to the file.  This is not a good solution for downloading large files.

Comment: @im_nullable, good call -- I've added that to the post.

Comment: @dezza, what do you mean by "encoding"?  The output is a capture of the content sent in the body of the HTTP GET response, be it binary files, HTML, or whatever else you ask for.  It's really hard to see how a .py file can "break" by copying its raw contents from one place to another, unless the web server is the one messing with it first.....

Comment: @Warren Try https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py with above command and run it with Python 2.7, then try another tool like wget and it will work fine.

Comment: @dezza I've updated the answer with a different approach.  Try it again.

Comment: @Warren +1 :) better and shorter.

Comment: p.s. To save some typing, you can type -o then hit tab to get tab completion for -OutFile

Comment: Thanks. Do you by any chance know how to clean copy/clipboard from PS console without block-selecting ? It's irritating copying from PS because almost every long command wraps on the next line.

Comment: You can redirect the output of powershell to the clipboard by doing something like  "Get-PSDrive | clip".  Just be aware that it will rewrite the output as Unicode.

Comment: Also, the console in the Powershell ISE doesn't share the console's selection logic.  I suggest using that instead of the standard PS console.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're behind an authenticating firewall. You get an error "Proxy authentication required". You can fix this by running `$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient;  $wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true; $wc.Proxy.Credentials = $wc.Credentials`. You only need to do this once per session, it seems. (I'm not 100% sure why this works, it looks like the proxy is a session-level shared object...)

Comment: This uses IE, like everything in Powershell it's been done in a quick and dirty way, instead of just integrating wget or curl. But obviously if Microsoft did that it would ruin their licencing.

Comment: @ChrisS It doesn't use IE if you provide the -UseBasicParsing parameter.  (That's why this parameter is required for Server Core)

Comment: `converts the input to Unicode`: instead of `> out.html` you can use `| Set-Content out.html -Encoding Byte`, while not helpful for `iwr` since it has `-OutFile` now, it's good to know when writing binary data to files in other cmdlets

Answer (score 197):

If you just need to retrieve a file, you can use the [DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

Where `$url` is a string representing the file's URL, and `$path` is representing the local path the file will be saved to.

Note that `$path` must include the file name; it can't just be a directory.

Comment: So far this has been the best solution proposed. Also given that it seems I can rewrite it in one line format as `(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile( '$url, $path)` it is the best correspondence for `wget` I have seen so far. Thanks!

Comment: As a side-note you can also do this asynchronously using something like (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFileAsync(url,filePath)

Comment: Can we fetch a particular text via Webclient and outout to a notepad ? thanks

Comment: Yes, this works out of the box on Windows 7 ([that comes with PowerShell 2.0](http://superuser.com/questions/650814)). Sample:  `$client.DownloadFile( "http://blog.stackexchange.com/", "c:/temp2/_Download.html")`

Comment: Why does this use 100% of one of my CPUs?

Comment: @jsalonen and since that's .NET, it works on PS 2.0, which I am restricted to at them moment.

Comment: For just getting a url and ignoring the results (e.g., part of an IIS warmup script) use DownloadData: `(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData($url) | Out-Null`

Comment: Error messages are very unhelpful; if `$path` is a directory or existing file, it throws a generic Exception. Ah, Microsoft.

Comment: Nice! Invoke-WebRequest blows up in my packer job, complaining about "Out of Memory". The WebClient.DownloadFile works a treat.

Comment: Running `client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient` gave me the error `client : The term 'client' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` However, the one-liner worked.

Comment: So much faster than wget! Had issues with wget timeouts for moderately large files.

Answer (score 104):

There is [`Invoke-WebRequest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) in the upcoming PowerShell version 3:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://www.google.com/ -OutFile c:\google.html
```

Comment: all the elegance of `dd`...

Comment: @gWaldo you are kidding–this is a joy to use (speaking as someone just learning PS)

Comment: I just mean that the `-Outfile` parameter seems extraneous when you could just use `>` (to overwrite) or `>>` (to append) to a file.

Comment: @gWaldo or even deduce the filename from the URL just like `wget` does :)

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest $url ($url -split "/")[-1]`. Unfortunately fails if the URL ends with a slash. Should be pretty straightforward to improve.

Comment: And as of PS 4.0, `wget` and `curl` are aliasted to `Invoke-WebRequest` (`iwr`) by default :D

Comment: @Bob Thx, Feel free to edit the answer and include these aliases!

Comment: @gWaldo PowerShell can be quite slick.

You can use shortcuts

`(iwr http://www.google.com/).Content > google.html`

or use arguments

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.google.com" -OutFile google.html`.

It's important to realize that in PowerShell the pipe is an object pipe, not just a character pipe so the output of `Invoke-WebRequest` isn't a stream of the file but rather an object where you'll need to use `.Content`. Try this:

`$foo = Invoke-WebRequest http://www.google.com` then `$foo | Get-Member` then `$foo.StatusCode` or `$foo.Content`.

Comment: On Windows 2016 Core / Standard I had to pass `-usebasicparsing` as otherwise it was complaining about missing internet explorer engine

Answer (score 20):

It's a bit messy but there is [this blog post](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/11/25/PowerShell-_2D00_-How-to-download-a-file_3F00_.aspx) which gives you instructions for downloading files.

Alternatively (and this is one I'd recommend) you can use BITS:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -source "http://urlToDownload"
```

It will show progress and will download the file to the current directory.

Comment: BITS relies on support at the server end, if available this works in the background and you can get progress updates with other cmdlets.

Comment: I tried to fetch http://www.google.com/, but all I get is `Start-BitsTransfer : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`. I'm puzzled :|

Comment: @jsalonen I think that BITS will only download files rather than pages. As Richard says it relies on some server side support (although I don't think it's Microsoft specific).

Comment: I see and I think I get the point in using BITS, however, its not what I'm looking for in here.

Answer (score 8):

**PowerShell V4 One-liner:**

```
(iwr http://blog.stackexchange.com/).Content >index.html`
```

or

```
(iwr http://demo.mediacore.tv/files/31266.mp4).Content >video.mp4
```

---

This is basically [Warren's (awesome) V3 one-liner](https://superuser.com/a/693179/278239) *(thanks for this!)* - with just a tiny change in order to make it work in a V4 PowerShell.

[Warren's one-liner](https://superuser.com/a/693179/278239) - which simply uses `wget` rather than `iwr` - should still work for **V3** (At least, I guess; didn't tested it, though). Anyway. But when trying to execute it in a **V4** PowerShell (as I tried), you'll see PowerShell failing to resolve `wget` as a valid cmdlet/program.

For those interested, that is - as I picked up from [Bob's comment](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) in reply to [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/460240/278239) *(thanks, man!)* - because **as of PowerShell V4, `wget` and `curl` are aliased to `Invoke-WebRequest`, set to `iwr` by default**. Thus, `wget` can not be resolved *(as well as `curl` can not work here)*.

Answer (score 8):

If your Windows is new enough (like version 1809 or newer), there's a "real" curl available. curl has the command-Line option "-O" (capital letter O; small letter won't do the same!) The option "-O", alternatively "--remote-name" tells curl, that the saved file gets the same name as the file-name part of the URL.

One needs to start this as "curl.exe", to discern it from the Alias "curl" for "Invoke-WebRequest". Incidentally it works in cmd.exe without changes.

Using the same example as in another answer here

```
curl.exe -O http://demo.mediacore.tv/files/31266.mp4
```

(The site won't allow me to add this as a comment, since I apparently need more "reputation" for that - so it gets a new answer)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a PowerShell function that resolves short URLs before downloading the file

```
function Get-FileFromUri {  
    param(  
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string]
        [Alias('Uri')]
        $Url,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
        [string]
        [Alias('Folder')]
        $FolderPath
    )
    process {
        try {
            # resolve short URLs
            $req = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Url)
            $req.Method = "HEAD"
            $response = $req.GetResponse()
            $fUri = $response.ResponseUri
            $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fUri.LocalPath);
            $response.Close()
            # download file
            $destination = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
            if ($FolderPath) { $destination = $FolderPath }
            if ($destination.EndsWith('\')) {
                $destination += $filename
            } else {
                $destination += '\' + $filename
            }
            $webclient = New-Object System.Net.webclient
            $webclient.downloadfile($fUri.AbsoluteUri, $destination)
            write-host -ForegroundColor DarkGreen "downloaded '$($fUri.AbsoluteUri)' to '$($destination)'"
        } catch {
            write-host -ForegroundColor DarkRed $_.Exception.Message
        }  
    }  
}
```

Use it like this to download the file to the current folder:

```
Get-FileFromUri http://example.com/url/of/example/file
```

Or to download the file to a specified folder:

```
Get-FileFromUri http://example.com/url/of/example/file  C:\example-folder
```

Answer (score 2):

The following function will get a URL.

```
function Get-URLContent ($url, $path) {
  if (!$path) {
      $path = Join-Path $pwd.Path ([URI]$url).Segments[-1]
  }
  $wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
  $wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
  $wc.Proxy.Credentials = $wc.Credentials
  $wc.DownloadFile($url, $path)
}
```

Some comments:

1. The last 4 lines are only needed if you are behind an authenticating proxy. For simple use, `(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $path)` works fine.
2. The path *must* be absolute, as the download is not done in your current directory, so relative paths will result in the download getting lost somewhere.
3. The `if (!$path) {...}` section handles the simple case where you just want to download the file to the current directory using the name given in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows 10 bash shell which includes wget once the windows feature is setup.

How to install Ubuntu bash shell on Windows:

[YouTube: Running Bash on Ubuntu on Windows!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nu1azCGrxpw)

[Windows Subsystem for Linux Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide)

Comment: Consider adding some quoted reference to this answer supporting what you state in case the link ever dies so the answer content is still available that is currently only available via that link per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-WebRequest with -outfile parameter expects a string, so if your filename starts with a number, and not enclosed in quotes, no output file is created.

eg. `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.google.com/" -outfile "2.pdf"`

This does not affect filenames starting with a letter.

Comment: This solution is mentioned in other answers (`wget` is an alias of `Invoke-WebRequest`, and one similar to the above)

Comment: The point of the answer was to emphasise the note. None of the answers deal with no file being created due to the syntax error.

Comment: That should really be a comment on the other answer[s]

Comment: This answer is not provided in other answers nor similar to the one above.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell [Invoke-RestMethod](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2) may have fewer dependencies than other methods ... in case you have a minimal (or older) Windows Server installed.

See error reported at [Running Invoke-WebRequest as System account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52942899):

> Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the
> Internet Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's
> first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the
> UseBasicParsing parameter and try again.

---

This can be an alternative to applying the `-UseBasicParsing` option that is, in some cases, required with `wget` or [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest).

However, the displayed response may be in a different format, based on data parsing:

> PowerShell formats the response based to the data type. For an RSS or
> ATOM feed, PowerShell returns the Item or Entry XML nodes. For
> JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) or XML, PowerShell converts, or
> deserializes, the content into [PSCustomObject] objects.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you to get around the no browser initialized stuff.  Note the "-UseBasicParsing" param.

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost -UseBasicParsing
```

Comment: (1) What is “the no browser initialized stuff”? (2) Note that the accepted answer already mentions ``-UseBasicParsing``.