# Linux "get" command in windows

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

Is there a windows equivalent of Linux's "get" command in windows that I can use to obtain remote objects? I want to be able to have a batch file download a remote file on execution.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/362152/native-alternative-to-wget-in-windows-powershell

Comment: Any restriction that prevents you from using wget, curl and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use windows powershell, is this what you are looking for:

> If you just need to retrieve a file, you can use the DownloadFile
>   method of the WebClient object:
>
> `$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient`
>
> `$client.DownloadFile( $url,$path )`
>
> Where $url is a string representing the file's URL, and $path
>   representing the local path the file will be saved to.
>
> Note that $path must include the file name; it can't just be a
>   directory.

Comes from this topic: [Native alternative to wget in Windows PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/questions/362152/native-alternative-to-wget-in-windows-powershell)

Comment: This is just a batch file run from an elevated command prompt. Will this work in a plain old command prompt?

Comment: I don't think it will run in the CMD that comes with XP/Vista. From Win7 onwards, PowerShell comes out of the box. If you don't have PowerShell and you are familiar with unix shell script, why not try Cygwin?

Comment: It's a server 2008 r2 box and I've not seen Cygwin. Is there a way without using Cygwin? (get is probably the only linux command I'd be using)

Comment: I believe it is possible to install PowerShell on server 2008: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2521/windows_server_2008_install_windows_powershell/

or

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847837.aspx

Would that be an option for you?

Comment: I have powershell, I may just write a small program for it instead as I'd like it to work on windows systems without powershell as well.