# What version of PowerShell comes with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I am attempting to create a solution to launch remote processes in an environment which is very stable, and I know the user base will have Windows 7 - most will have no updates to it though.

*[Remote SSIS Package Execution with PowerShell 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/10/11/remote-ssis-package-execution-with-powershell-2-0.aspx)* says that Windows 7 comes with [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) 2.0 and would therefore be capable of the remote execution, but I seem to remember having to upgrade my machine to PowerShell 2. I am currently on v3 of PowerShell and don't have access to the machines on which the script would need to run.

What version of PowerShell comes with Windows 7 out of the box?

Comment: You have the correct answer from the horse's mouth... Why ask again?

Comment: The path it is installed in on one of the machines is %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

It is a strange path to install v2.0, no?

Comment: I haven't updated Powershell on my Win7 machine and it's on v1.

Comment: Even though the path is 
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
and made me think it was v1, I ran the following cmd and found it is in fact v2.  
Post this and I will mark it as an answer.  I cannot as not enough status...

PS C:\Users\tk> $psversiontable.psversion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1

Comment: @JohnBensin - I used get-host and you're right, it is version 2.0

Comment: Thanks John, that also works (as does $psversiontable.psversion)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/how-to-determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed

Comment: @AthomSfere [Cross-site duplicates are allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/218097), and since linked posts don't show up in the sidebar across SE sites, it's useful to have the information here as well.

Comment: @AthomSfere - Not same question anyway, as it is not "how to determine version" but "what version comes in Win7 without updates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently installed Windows 7 on a fresh system, and running `get-host` in PowerShell tells me I'm running version 2.0, even though it's installed in the v1.0 folder.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\user> get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : 61ef8a3b-0212-4743-87a1-eb2c00fb1e29
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserI
                   nterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Comment: `$PSVersionTable` would be a better way to check than `get-host`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1825807/1394393.

Comment: Here is also a nice Microsoft Blog posting which talks about $PSVersionTable and the needed KBs to download the update. See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/09/weekend-scripter-install-powershell-4-0-in-windows-7/

Comment: A question with more comprehensive answers regarding finding the PowerShell version is *[Determine installed PowerShell version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585)*.

Comment: Is this answer reliable, since the linked question says `get-host` doesn't return the correct information?  Also, does the answer depend on what version of Windows 7 is installed?  (e.g. do some installers come with SP1 built in?)