# How to download files from a windows command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to download using the Windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line)

Let's say you are on a Windows XP machine without a browser. Without using another computer to download and save to a USB drive, how might you use the Windows command line to download a browser? I'm assuming curl isn't installed, but there must be some sort of command available.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know of a native downloader. I use [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)  and it includes wget

Alternatively there is [wget for window](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

If you have powershell installed, the following might work as well
[Earlier discussion on similar question.](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget)

Comment: This is by no means spam, but your post would be easier to understand if you explain what you're linking to.  This will also ensure that the post remains useful should the links become invalid.

Comment: ...and how would you download wget without using a browser?